# Filter array of objects using another array with filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter

There is a question how to make multiply filter in JS.
For example:

```
const people = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      eyes: {
        color: 'black',
        size: 'small',
      },
      age: 30,
    },
    {
      name: 'Paul',
      eyes: {
        color: 'grey',
        size: 'small',
      },
      age: 30,
    },
    {
      name: 'Todd',
      eyes: {
        color: 'black',
        size: 'big',
      },
      age: 30,
    },
    {
      name: 'Jax',
      eyes: {
        color: 'grey',
        size: 'big',
      },
      age: 27,
    },
  ];

  const filters = ['Paul'];
```

I need to create multiply filters. For example filtering will be: by age, by hair color, by name;

```
const filteredPersons = people.filter(person => filters.includes(person.age)).filter(person => filters.includes(person.eyes,color)).filter(person => filters.includes(person.name))
```

in this case if I will have this filters

```
const filters = ['Paul', 30, 'grey'];
```

I will find person Paul in this array. BUT! For example if I want to find only person 30 years old

```
const filters = [30];

const filteredPersons = people.filter(person => filters.includes(person.age)).filter(person => filters.includes(person.eyes,color)).filter(person => filters.includes(person.name))

console.log(filteredPersons)
```

filteredPersons will return empty array. How can I add conditions when there is no matches during filtering by age - it will ignore this filter and continue searching by eye color. And if it is nothing here too - it will ignore .filter by color and cnotinue searching by name?

Thank you!

Comment: @pavel-zakharov Are you expecting the array to have the values in the format `[name, age, color]` or they can be shuffled and may be pointing to any attribute?

Comment: I would say, your input data is a bit poorly designed for that kind of filtering: first, you would be much better off having more _flat_ items within your `people` array (without nesting properties more than 1 level deep); second, it would be better to have object (not array as a filter) to have an idea, whether 'grey' would correspond to eyes color or name

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji they can be in any place in array, so yes - shuffled

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov this is simple data structure just as an example. The final structure will be bigger, but the main thing is to find how to ignore .filter if there is nothing that can bi filtered based on array of filters